# How to constrain a Rails route based on an array of subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4.2 application with a set of routes that are constrained to a subdomain.

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
  # ...
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to specify multiple subdomains (both `admin` and `admin.staging`). How can I specify multiple subdomains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, e.g.:

```
constraints subdomain: /^admin|admin\.staging$/ do
  # ...
end
```

...or...

```
constraints subdomain: /^admin(\.staging)?$/ do
  # ...
end
```

You can also use a lambda:

```
constraints subdomain: ->(req) { %w[ admin admin.staging ].include?(req.subdomain) } do
  # ...
end
```

You can read the documentation for `constraints` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints

Answer (score 13):

Even though it's not documented, you can also pass an array of subdomains:

```
constraints subdomain: ['admin', 'admin.staging'] do
  # ...
end
```